# Is there a Java IDE for iPad which can compile and run Java locally?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, java, development, ide

I'm about to have a coding session with some buddies. Problem is, one doesn't have a laptop. He's pretty new to programming so I was going to set him up something either on a rickety laptop or my iPad with a bluetooth keyboard / mouse.

Is there any app that would give me these capabilities:

- Java IDE
- compile java locally
- run java locally

Comment: If he intends to be a programmer in any capacity, investing in a cheap laptop (or chromebook wiped with a linux distro installed) is a necessity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are web-based IDEs that support Java like [IDE One](http://ideone.com/) and [CodeBox](https://www.codebox.io/stack/java) that should work from an iPad. Obviously there are limitations with both but they might suffice.

This is my immediate thought, because I believe Apple have rules against people creating apps that include their own runtime. Which I'd assume you'd require if you wanted to compile Java code directly on an iOS device.

Comment: That's what I feared. I imagine Apple wouldn't be ok with this either. I'll take a look at the links you provided and see if they will suffice. Thank you!

Comment: There are some iOS apps that let you write and compile Java code, but they offload the compilation to a server online to get around Apple's rules. For example [JVM Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/jvm-programming-language/id486207896).

Comment: Ah! That's very smart. Perfect, I'll give those a go. Thank you very much

Comment: I get around these limitations with a server and [Prompt by panic](https://panic.com/prompt/). It's not a native IDE, but it gets the job done for me.

Comment: Code box seems to have been purchased in early 2015. Now they aren't accepting sign ups. Doesn't bode well for the platform IMO.

Comment: Pythonista was available in 2012 (https://www.macstories.net/stories/automating-ios-how-pythonista-changed-my-workflow/); why can't there be a similar offline Java development app?

Comment: I don't see anything in the review guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#performance) that says that it's not allowed. Rather, it says "Apps should be self-contained in their bundles, and may not read or write data outside the designated container area, nor may they download, install, or execute code which introduces or changes features or functionality of the app, including other apps." (cont'd)

Comment: "Educational apps designed to teach, develop, or allow students to test executable code may, in limited circumstances, download code provided that such code is not used for other purposes. Such apps must make the source code provided by the Application completely viewable and editable by the user."

Answer (score -1):

use PICO COMPILER APP on AppStore, works well, but you cant use SWING components as far as i am aware

Answer (score -1):

You can use iDos and if you are running iOS 8.4 or less you can easily use iFunbox and add dos Java compiler in the iDos app on your phone and use it. Note app sandbox is only available until iOS 8.4. If you are using 8.4 or above you have to go for online compilers, only there is no option available there.